# How to automatically load images using PHP JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am new to this and I would be grateful if someone can help. The code below I use to pull texts from mysql database and works fine to fetch the data without refreshing the page. What I am trying to do now is do the same for the images stored in the database but they are not displaying.

```js
<?php 

    include_once('db.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = array();

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res) )
        array_push($result, array('image1'  => $row['image1']));

    echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
    ?>
```

```html
 $(document).ready(function () {
        done();
    });     

    function done() {
        setTimeout(function () {       
            updates();
            done();
        }, 200);
    }

    function update_content() {
      $.getJSON("showImages.php", function (data) {
        $("#Imageslider").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
          $("#Imageslider"").append("<img" +this['image1'] + "/>");
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
          update_content();
        }, 1000);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Im confused, is `update_content` and `updates` suppost to be the same function?

Comment: `"<img src=" +this['image1'] + "/>"`

Comment: Unfortunately I just get a blank screen :(. Do you have a better method that works? @Mohamed-Yousef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many functions

In the code below I am assuming that your PHP produces this

```
{ "result" : [ { "image1":"someurl"},{ "image1":"someurl"}] }
```

If so, you can do

```js
function update_content() {
  $.getJSON("showImages.php", function(data) {
    $("#Imageslider").html(
      data.result.map(({image1}) => `<img src="${image1}" />`).join("")
    );
    setTimeout(update_content, 3000); // if you want to update the interface every 3 seconds
  })
}
$(function() {
  update_content()
})
```

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance. How would I link the data.result to mysql code please. I really appreciate this help thank you

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.

Where does this code go?
data.result = [ { "image1":"someurl"},{ "image1":"someurl"}]

Comment: The JavaScript I posted should replace all your JavaScript if I have understood the issue

Comment: I have tried your code and still getting a black screen not sure where I am going wrong. I have loaded the php file and the images are showing. Any further advise?

Comment: I have noticed my PHP file is not returning the data. Any suggestion why that might be? what can I fix in my PHP code. Thank you

Comment: Turn on error reporting in the php (search it up)

Comment: Thank you for all your help. 

My php file is now executing 
{ "result" : [ { "image1":"someurl"},{ "image1":"someurl"}] }

My html is displaying small icon images. I cannot see any errors in the console. Any suggestions on what I can tweak?

Comment: Sorry that posted before I finished typing :D

Comment: "someurl" of course need to be "/images/image1.jpg" or something - what do you have in  $row['image1'] - and "/images/image1.jpg" must exist

Comment: "someurl" comes out with a lot of characters 

{"result":[{"image1":"\/9j\/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP\/sABFEdWNreQABA"

Looks like this is the images itself in text.

Comment: That would be wrong. Then you need to EITHER have another php serve the image OR convert to Base 64 and use a data uri

Comment: Then have `\`<img src="data:image/png;base64,${image1}" />\``

Comment: This has worked. Thank you so much for all your help. I really do appreciate it

Comment: @mplungjan-I wonder if you can help me incorporate an image slideshow to the images I have just pulled from the data base with the two refreshes clashing with each other. Refresh 1 is to update content. Refresh 2 is to update the slideshow